# Prevent an UIAlertView from closing on PositiveButton click

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am developing mobile application using Xamarin.Forms. I have requirement of getting input in the dialog box. So, i have used UIAlertView for getting text input as like below.

[image]

I need to prevent an UIAlertView from closing on button click. I need to retain the UIAlertView dialog box even after the action initiated.

Can anyone please help me on this?

Regards,

Karthikeyan

Comment: Sorry can you tell us what your reasoning for this is? do you need them to input more information after they've provided an answer to the first question?

Comment: I need to validate the user input after the save button click. Here validate means 
* validating the special characters.
* Validating the name is that name already exist.

Comment: well what would be wrong with re-displaying the popup should the validations fail?

Answer (score 1):

You could create a custom UIView for this using a Xib file, however if you have no objection to the dialog closing and reopening should it encounter a validation issue then the following would work fine.

EDIT: Adjusted to allow you to pass back the validation message, as the primary message on the UIAlertView.

```
private string message = string.Empty();

public void recursiveDialog()
{
    string input = string.Empty();

    if(message == string.Empty()) { message = "Please enter the view name"}

    var alert = UIAlertController.Create ("Save View", message, UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);

    alert.AddTextField ((field) => {
    field.Placeholder = "view name";});

    alert.AddAction (UIAlertAction.Create ("Cancel", UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, null));

    alert.AddAction (UIAlertAction.Create ("Save", UIAlertActionStyle.Default, action => {
               input = alert.TextFields[0].Text
    }));

    if (alert.PopoverPresentationController != null)
        alert.PopoverPresentationController.BarButtonItem = myItem;

    PresentViewController (alert, animated: true, 
    action => {

        // when a dialog is selected and returns, run validation

        if(input == [whatever you want to use to validate it against])
        {
                    // it failed because it already exists for example so change our message

                    message = "That view name already exists, try again.";

            // already exists, so re-run method.
            recursiveDialog();
        }
        else
        {
            // doesn't alread exist so carry on with whatever you want to do with the name provided.

                    // clear your message variable
                    message = string.Empty();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks! i'll try this. One more doubt, Do you have idea on how to show the validation message in the Alert box (with TextField)?

Comment: @Karthik I've made a change to the code above, that should allow you to inform a user why the dialog has reappeared.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! But i need to show the message below that TextField.

Thanks again for your responses.

Comment: @Karthik no problem, if you're after that kind of functionality then a custom view that you present in the context of the current view is the way to go.